# Type Mismatch when passing an integer result to an integer type variable

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim codeStart As String
codeStart = Evaluate("CELL(""address"",OFFSET(" & startRange & ",2,0,1,1))")

Dim agentTotal As String
agentTotal = Evaluate("CELL(""address"",INDEX(" & startRange & ":" & _
"$A$10000,MATCH(""               Total*""," & startRange & ":$A$10000,0)))")

Dim numberOfCodes As String
numberOfCodes = Evaluate("ROW(" & agentTotal & ")-ROW(" & codeStart & ")")
MsgBox numberOfCodes
```

The first two variables properly pass as strings when tested with a `Msgbox`

I've tried setting numberOfCodes to a few different variable types and putting `CInt` in front of `Evaluate` but no dice..any ideas?

Comment: What value does `numberOfCodes` have post `Evaluate`?

Comment: In this example, 1. Subtracts $A$56 - $A$55

Comment: Do a `trim` on it & see if it can be converted to a number using `val`. i.e. `msgbox(val(numberOfCodes))`.

Comment: @YowE3K so the purpose of these cell/address functions is to break this report of Agent's activities into certain sections. Each agent has a line of one or more "codes" or activities. The difference in which row has the Total string and the row where the codes start (which is always 2 rows below the Agent's ID) will equal the number of codes, which I will be using as the maximum number of times to run another loop within that section

Comment: I'm just going to take these evaluates and and tack on .Row and pass them to integers and just subtract agentTotalRow from codeStartRow. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform the following statement

```
Evaluate("ROW(" & agentTotal & ")-ROW(" & codeStart & ")")
```

it returns a `Variant` (which is what `Evaluate` will always return) but, because you are using `ROW` (which can return an array), it will either return a `Variant/Variant(1 To 1)` (if only a single row is being returned) or a `Variant/Variant(1 To x, 1 To 1)` (if x rows are being returned).

Normally a `Variant` can be cast to a `String` or an `Integer` (if the value permits) but, because in this case it is a `Variant` array, it can't be converted to a single value.

In your case, the following code would have worked:

```
Dim numberOfCodes As Variant
numberOfCodes = Evaluate("ROW(" & agentTotal & ")-ROW(" & codeStart & ")")
MsgBox numberOfCodes(1)
```

or

```
Dim numberOfCodes As Integer
numberOfCodes = Evaluate("ROW(" & agentTotal & ")-ROW(" & codeStart & ")")(1)
MsgBox numberOfCodes
```

but another way would have been to simply say:

```
Dim numberOfCodes As Long
numberOfCodes = Range(agentTotal).Row - Range(codeStart).Row
```

---

But that simplification could have gone back a lot further.  For instance you are using the code `Evaluate("CELL(""address"",OFFSET(" & startRange & ",2,0,1,1))")` to find an address, but you are really after the row number, so you could leave out that and calculate `numberOfCodes` as

```
numberOfCodes = Range(agentTotal).Row - Range(startRange).Row - 2
```

And you can also get rid of `AgentTotal` by using

```
numberOfCodes = Application.Match("               Total*", _
                                  Range(startRange, "$A$10000"),0) - 3
```

which just calculates the number of rows (inclusive) from `startRange` to the "Total" and subtracts 3 (to exclude the two headers(?) and the total).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to take these evaluates and and tack on .Row and pass them to integers and just subtract agentTotalRow from codeStartRow. Works perfectly now.